# WebService classes unaccessible

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I have a Solution with 2 projects, ServiceProj and UIProj (winforms). ServiceProj contains a WebService, a bunch of classes, and a `DataSet`. When I add the `WebReference` of ServiceProj to the UIProj, I can see the web methods, but cannot see the classes of ServiceProj.

My classes are all public, non-static, and they are in **ServiceProj.Classes.Entities** namespace. I can access them inside web service and therefore use them in web methods and I can call the web methods in my UIProj, but I cannot directly access the classes from UIProj.

Do you know where I may be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see the classes in from another project you have to add a project reference as well (right click references, add reference) to that project.

By adding a web reference to another project you are generating:

- proxy class containing all your web mthods
- class definitions for all your method parameters [if required]
- class definitions for all your method return types [if required]

So with only your web reference you'll be able to see all web methods and custom types that are returned by or passed to the web methods.

[answer is based on VS2010 and not VS2012]

Comment: Thanks Quintion, 2012 is also the same. Problem solved. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [XmlInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx) attribute on an exposed class

---

[Expose additional classes in ASP.NET 2.0 webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300410/expose-additional-classes-in-asp-net-2-0-webservice)